# Add page numbers in FOOTER while generating the PDF document using play framework 1.2.7 PDF module version 0.9

Tags: pdf, playframework, footer, page-numbering

I am looking at adding page numbers in the footer section while generating the pdf document using PDF module v 0.9 in the PLAY framework version 1.2.7. Any guidance/help will be nice.

Thank You.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe it's too late now for the answer, but I post it anyway. It could be useful to someone else.

I'm using PLAY 1.3.1 and the PDF module 0.9.

You can add page number like this :

```
File pdf = new File(Play.tmpDir.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + "My-new-document.pdf");
PDF.Options options = new PDF.Options();

options.FOOTER = "<div style='float:right;'><p style='font-family:Arial, sans-serif; text-align: right; font-size: 10px;'>"
    + "Page <pagenumber>/<pagecount></p></div>";


PDF.writePDF(pdf, "pdf/emptyPdf.html", textToRender, options);
```